# Array declaration in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Hello everyone I am currently learning solidity and came across different ways of declaring arrays in solidity.

`uint[2] stateArray1 = [uint(1),2];`

`uint[2] stateArray2 = [uint(3),4];`

I understand both arrays can only contain unsigned integers and have a size of 2.
What I don't understand is the uint(1) and uint(3)
declared beside the default array parameters.

Thank you for helping clarify this for me.

Answer (score 1):

`uint(1)` explicitly casts the value of `1` to the type of `uint256` (as `uint` without the specified length is an alias of `uint256`). Same goes for `uint(3)` or generally `uint(<N>)`.

This was a workaround for older versions of the JavaScript EVM emulator included in Remix IDE, that in some cases treated values 255 and smaller as `uint8` (max value 255), so it incorrectly showed a type error (trying to assign `uint8` into an `uint256[]` array). The issue has been fixed, so now you don't have to explicitly specify the type anymore:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint[2] stateArray1 = [1, 2];
    uint[2] stateArray2 = [3, 4];
}
```

Comment: @cryptogeek237 if the answer is helpful just accept it instead of typing plain 'thank you' :)